# How to disable function logs on Gatsby?

Tags: node.js, typescript, logging, gatsby

So, I am new to gatsby and I am trying to build gatsby functions the way it is written in this documentation:  https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/functions/getting-started/

However, whenever I execute the function, it logs something like "Executed function "/api/test" in 27ms".

Now, since this will be a frequently called function in the future, I wish to disable the logs preferably just for this function OR for all the functions under /api folder.

Can anyone help please me out?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`gatsby-plugin-remove-console`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-remove-console/) plugin:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-remove-console'
  ],
};
```

There isn't any built-in method of disabling logs as far as I know so try using the plugin. However, I'm not sure about its use in Gatsby functions...

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. But I am guessing, this will this disable all the gatsby build logs right?

Is there a way in which we can specify in the code for a specific gatsby function to not  log?

Comment: You have an object exposed to exlude the logs by type (warning, error, etc):   `options: {exclude: ['error', 'warn'],}`